# Is there a better way to log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging

Whats the simplest / most efficient way to log a Javascript / jQuery output?

At the moment, I am using something like `alert('foobar');` blocks in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
console.log('foobar');
```

Then check your JS console.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

console.log is better if the browser supports it.

```
if (window.console)
    console.log('foobar');
```

Comment: This will still fall flat because `window.console` will be undefined in browsers (IE) that don't support it. You're better off starting with `if(window.console)`.

Comment: I think a better solution is to have the a script like the following so you don't have to check every time you log. `if (!window.console){console.log = alert}`. Also, IE does support console.log, if you have the web developer tools.

Comment: Building off of Juan, I check for window.console once at the beginning of my script, and if it doesn't exist, I declare stub functions for the entire logging API (which varies by browser/plug-in).  This allows me to have my logging infrastructure, without wrecking my code if I want to show it to others.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute simplest, use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable).

> Include the following code at the top of the `<head>` of your page:
>
> `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`

**That's it!**  It will bootstrap a logging console in your browser window, no matter which (modern) browser you're working with.

The [Firebug console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) can be found at the Firebug wiki.

There are a few other options for logging in JavaScript, but if you just want something simple that works... Firebug Lite is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) (disclosure: I wrote it), which works in all major browsers, has a nice logging console with search and filtering and can also be used to send log messages to the server.

Comment: I can vouch for Tim, log4javascript is quality logging goodness.